# JavaScript forEach() method confusion

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, foreach

Using nodejs in Ubuntu. I've been reading the MDN docs for the JavaScript `forEach()` method. I understand there are other ways to do this, but I learn by doing; I'm trying to make the array `copy` a unique collection of the values in the `arr` array; no duplicates. I want to do this using the `forEach()` method.

The setup:

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3, 2];
var copy = [];
```

So why does this work?

```
copy.includes(1); // returns false
```

While this doesn't?

```
arr.forEach(function(element, copy) {
 if (!copy.includes(element)) {
   copy.push(element);
 }
});
```

And here is the error:

```
TypeError: copy.includes is not a function
    at repl:2:11
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at repl:1:5
    at ContextifyScript.Script.runInThisContext (vm.js:23:33)
    at REPLServer.defaultEval (repl.js:339:29)
    at bound (domain.js:280:14)
    at REPLServer.runBound [as eval] (domain.js:293:12)
    at REPLServer.onLine (repl.js:536:10)
    at emitOne (events.js:101:20)
    at REPLServer.emit (events.js:191:7)
```

Comment: Learning by doing and using Stackoverflow is a great way to learn JavaScript. You might also enjoy the alternative methods to remove duplicates described in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229645/remove-duplicates-from-javascript-array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second argument of forEach callback is the index, And by mentioning copy as a second argument, you are getting the index and not the array declare before. So what you are trying to do is `0.includes` which actually is not a function. Removing the second argument will solve your problem

```
arr.forEach(function(element) {
 if (!copy.includes(element)) {
copy.push(element);
}
});
```

Comment: That did the trick; I now see how I misunderstood the docs. Why are the MDN docs so unfriendly to noobs? I spent two hours reading up about the `forEach()` method.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
arr.forEach(function(element) {
 if (!copied.includes(element)) {
   copied.push(element);
 }
});
```

Second argument of forEach callback is index, not array you're trying to fill. Also, you referenced `copy` which is `undefined`, while correct variable named is `copied` according to your code example.

## Edit

After you've edited your code you use name `copy` both for array and second argument of forEach callback (why the heck you need second argument of forEach callback - which by the way - is index, not "copy" - whatever copy you mean : P).

So, you get an error that `Number.prototype` doesn't have method called `includes()` which is true, because index is a `Number`.

To sum up:

```
arr.forEach(function(element) {
 if (!copy.includes(element)) {
   copy.push(element);
 }
});
```

Comment: Please see the edit. The array of unique values is always called `copy`. That was an editing error on my part; my apologies.

Comment: You name 2 variables exactly the same. You can't call second argument of forEach callback also a `copy`.

Comment: @SeanValdivia You haven't fixed the problem. You have `copy` here for no apparent reason: `function(element, copy) <----`